# Collapsing columns in r to form one column of delimited strings

Tags: r, delimiter

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(a = c("1", "2", "3"), b = c("Tom", "Jen", "Rob"
), c = c("Wrist", "Ankle", "Neck")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I'm trying to collapse my columns into a single column where each row contains a single text string comprised of data from each column separated by a delimiter (specifically a ; [colon]).

My current code converts my data into a text string but instead of multiple rows it's a single cell containing all data in the data frame:

```
data.frame(format_delim(df[1:nrow(df),],";", append = FALSE, col_names = FALSE, quote_escape = FALSE))
```

What should I do instead to obtain the following data frame?

```
structure(list(c..1.Tom.Wrist....2.Jen.Ankle....3.Rob.Neck.. = c("1;Tom;Wrist", 
"2;Jen;Ankle", "3;Rob;Neck")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Thanks. Hope this was easy to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use vectorized option with `do.call`

```
data.frame(col1 = do.call(paste, c(df, sep=";")))
#     col1
#1 1;Tom;Wrist
#2 2;Jen;Ankle
#3  3;Rob;Neck
```

Or if there are only few columns, we can use

```
with(df, paste(a, b, c, sep=";"))
```

---

Or another option is `unite`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    unite(col1, a, b, c, sep = ";")
#       col1
#1 1;Tom;Wrist
#2 2;Jen;Ankle
#3  3;Rob;Neck
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `apply()` solution:

```
#Code
out <- data.frame(v1=apply(df,1,function(x) paste0(x,collapse = ';')))
```

Output:

```
           v1
1 1;Tom;Wrist
2 2;Jen;Ankle
3  3;Rob;Neck
```

If you want to add the new variable to your original `df` you can use this:

```
#Code
df$var <- apply(df,1,function(x) paste0(x,collapse = ';'))
```

Output:

```
  a   b     c         var
1 1 Tom Wrist 1;Tom;Wrist
2 2 Jen Ankle 2;Jen;Ankle
3 3 Rob  Neck  3;Rob;Neck
```